# Using cordova plugin in angular 4 typescript file without ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova-plugins

I want to create a mobile app using angular4. I have created an angular project using angular CLI now I want to use/implement cordova plugin in my angular project.
How to do so without using IONIC framework?

For eg: I want to use cordova network information plugin to get the state of current network in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install and integrate your angular project with cordova (it's doable without IONIC).

I recomend to read these articles .

1) https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2 .

2) https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2017/05/31/update-angular-cli-and-apache-cordova

And use this repo as an example (`cordova-integration` branch):

https://github.com/becompany/angular2-rss-reader-tutorial/tree/cordova-integration

It's a bit old, but I'm using this approach for my Angular+Cordova projects even with Angular 5+.

There you can add any existing plugins to Cordova app.

UPDATE:
To use some plugin in TS file you should declare that variable in the file as on example below:

```
declare const PushNotifications;
```

And check it is it existing and use:

```
if (window['PushNotification']) {
  PushNotification.init(...);
}
```

Smth like that.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to create a basic project and build apk as well also i have added plugins in my cordova project but my real problem is how to use or import that plugin in my typescript file.